# Uploaded file changes name

Tags: google-colaboratory

When uploading a local file to Colab, if the file already exists it is saved with a different name e.g. 'filename (1).ext'. Is there any programmatic way to either enforce overwirte or get the new filename?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually delete the files then upload again.

```
import os
os.remove("filename.ext")
os.remove("filename (1).ext")
```